# Shadow catcher over baked floor

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking, shadowcatcher

I'm trying to make a semi real render without breaking Le VRam bank and time and so I decided to bake a combined on everything (even the floor) and then I placed my shadow catcher on the floor and put on a real time rendered object only to have it fly in a void above the ground  clearly the shadow catcher is transparent but not only to it self but to the object underneath it... how do I solve this? Thanks in advance for your reading and answering time!

Comment: Would you be able to add some screenshots to show what you mean? Having a hard time understanding the question

Comment: Okay sorry I didn't make the qustion clear enough, the idea is that I have a very dark scene which I have baked all lights on for ease of rendering, then I added a non light baked character onto the scene and I want her to cast shadow on the floor, so I added a shadow catcher and the shadow catcher made is transparent as if there is no object under it.

Comment: The floor is under the shadow catcher and it's not showing, just the shadow catcher making everything under it transparent.

Comment: The _Shadow Catcher_ is under the _Mask_ settings. It is basically used to create a mask in the shape of the object just like the _Holdout_ option, with the the difference that it still can receive shadows. A holdout object is used to "cut out" a hole in the render to use in the compositor for showing underlying footage or images by using the _Alpha Over_ for example. Any other 3D object behind a holdout object will be cut out, too.

Comment: So what is the situation? Render each on a different layer and compose them together?

Comment: Exactly. Depending on your scene, your character and the materials there are different ways to combine it more or less successful.

Comment: Alright, I guess I'll try this method, thanks a lot.